# настройка PyCharm для запуска pytest не работает

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pytest

настраиваю чтоб pytest запускался с кнопки в PyCharm появляется ошибка:

> ImportError: No module named ' amazing_hunting'

файл `pytest.ini`:

```ini
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = amazing_hunting.settings
```

папка с тестом внутри корневой папки `amazing_hunting`

тест срабатывает при запуске через консоль.

в `Run`/`Debug Configurations` в `Envitonment variables` выставлено `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = amazing_hunting.settings`

> pytest-django found a Django project in /home/odinokov/PycharmProjects/amazing_hunting (it contains manage.py) and added it to the Python path. If this is wrong, add "django_find_project = false" to pytest.ini and explicitly manage your Python path.

пробовал добавлять `django_find_project = false` в файл `pytest.ini` - не помогло